# Object not updating object from another object

Tags: javascript, object

I am creating 2 objects at launch
one is player and another rooms
player.name is currently set at 'todd'
when i lauch it asks for the name and then stores it in player.name

Object room has a 'key' story as below. i am trying to say welcome + player.name  but it takes todd and never anything else because it does not update player.name in the story.

how can i get the story to update?

I believe this is because the 2 objects are being created first before the planer.name gets updated so rooms.story already has todd set as the name and never updates, i have an update function but not sure how i can update the story

```
let player = {
  name: "todd",
  location: "start",
  items: ["one"]
}

let rooms = {
  start: {
    name: "outside",
    story: 'Welcome ' + player.name
  }
}
```

Rest of my code is 
https://jsfiddle.net/pwnuc62o/

index.html loads obj.js first which contains those 2 objects and then loads canvas.js which is the jsfiddle link

Thanks, sorry its a mess, im new and teaching myself pure JS by looking up what i want to do and implementing it and playing with it before looking at any libraries.

Comment: Your update function should just do `rooms.start.story = 'Welcom '+player.name;` after changing the player's name.

Comment: riiight, i was hoping there was a way i didnt have to do that so i could do something like..  story: "welcome " + player.neme + " some sort of story goes here afterwards etc etc..."  inside the object as i was going to just have a bunch of rooms in the object with different storyies and depending on player.location waht story shows up... but i guess i could just use a switch in the update :)

Answer (score 0):

It maybe easier to use a getter function instead of using another update function. You can define variable `room` as below.

```
let rooms = {
  start: {
    name: "outside",
    get story() { return 'Welcome ' + player.name }
  }
}
```

When you access `rooms.start.story`, js engine will call the getter function for you, no need to define an update function.